# Laravel 5.2 Could not encrypt data exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel and everything is working fine in my local environment. I've been uploading the project to a QA environment and everything has been working fine for months.

But yesterday we're a weird exception randomly. I say weird because it never happened before. Here's a short screenshot of the trace.

[image: EncryptException]

I've already tried artisan cache clear, clear-compiled, view clear, and those commands for clearing things but none of them worked.

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try changing app key by running `php artisan key:generate`?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it keeps happening.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this @Chuy? It's happening to me in Laravel 5.1, when I restart my server everything is back to normal, but as I am using the app the error appears again, starting by a json response failure, which let me to load the site, and then this encryption error. I don't see this documented anywhere.

Comment: @RogersSampaio hello mate, sadly I haven't figured out what is it.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have all these extentions
PHP >= 5.5.9
OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension

make sure the hosting provider dint change any of those settings.. 
also make sure the .env file properties.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the extensions are installed and the .env file it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to switch from php 5.6 to php 7.

From php5.6 to php7.0:

Apache:

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6; sudo a2enmod php7.0; sudo service apache2 restart
```

CLI:

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0
```

And when I entered localhost that exception was gone. I hope this can be a viable alternative.